# Looker Studio Community Connector error: The number of columns in the data does not match the number in the schema

Tags: looker-studio

I did followed looker studio get started guidlines and here is my Code.gs

```
var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
var DEFAULT_USER = "jefri";//PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('STACKOVERFLOW_USER_ID');
 
//https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#getconfig
function getConfig(){
  var config = cc.getConfig();
 
  config
    .newInfo()
    .setId('Instructions')
    .setText('Enter the user id to pull stackoverflow data');
 
  config
    .newTextInput()
    .setId('userId')
    .setName('Enter a single user id')
    .setHelpText('e.g "4541958"')
    .setPlaceholder(DEFAULT_USER)
    .setAllowOverride(true);
 
  //config.setDateRangeRequired(true);
 
  return config.build();
}
 
function getFields(){
  var fields = cc.getFields();
  var types = cc.FieldType;
  var aggregations = cc.AggregationType;
 
  var displayName = fields.newDimension().setId('display_name').setName('Display Name').setType(types.TEXT);
  var link = fields.newDimension().setId('link').setName('Link').setType(types.URL);
  //var goldBadges = fields.newMetric().setId('gold_badges').setName('Gold Badges').setType(types.NUMBER);
  var silverBadges = fields.newMetric().setId('silver_badges').setName('Silver Badges').setType(types.NUMBER);
 

  fields.setDefaultDimension(displayName.getId());
  fields.setDefaultMetric(silverBadges.getId());
  return fields;
}
 
function getSchema(request){
 var schema = {schema:getFields().build()};
 return schema;
}
 
function getData(request){
  console.log(request.fields);
 
  request.configParams = validateConfig(request.configParams);
 
  var requestedFieldIds = request.fields.map(function(field) {
    return field.name;
  });
  var requestedFields = getFields().forIds(requestedFieldIds);
 
  var data = formatData([
    {'display_name':'name 1','link':'https://website.com','gold_badges':87,'silver_badges':54},
    {'display_name':'name 2','link':'https://website.com','gold_badges':23,'silver_badges':34},
    {'display_name':'name 3','link':'https://website.com','gold_badges':12,'silver_badges':23},
    {'display_name':'name 4','link':'https://website.com','gold_badges':43,'silver_badges':56},
  ],requestedFields);
 
  console.log(data);
  var response = {
    "schems" : requestedFields.build(),
    "rows": data
  };

  console.log(response);
  return response;
}
 
function validateConfig(configParams){
  configParams = configParams || [];
  configParams.userId = configParams.userId || DEFAULT_USER;
 
  configParams.userId = configParams.userId.split(',').map(function(x){return x.trim();}).join(',');
 
  return configParams;
}
 
function formatData(response,requestedFields){
  return response.map(function(item) {
    var row = [];
    requestedFields.asArray().forEach(function (field) {
      switch (field.getId()) {
        case 'display_name':
          return row.push(item.display_name);
        case 'link':
          return row.push(item.link);
        case 'gold_badges':
          return row.push(item.gold_badges);
        case 'silver_badges':
          return row.push(item.silver_badges);
        default:
          return row.push('');
      }
    });
    return { values: row };
  });
}
```

And the console log for `console.log(request.fields);` is

```
[ { name: 'display_name' }, { name: 'silver_badges' } ]
```

And the console log for `console.log(response);` is

```
{ schems: 
   [ { semantics: [Object],
       dataType: 'STRING',
       name: 'display_name',
       label: 'Display Name',
       isDefault: true },
     { dataType: 'NUMBER',
       name: 'silver_badges',
       semantics: [Object],
       isDefault: true,
       label: 'Silver Badges' } ],
  rows: 
   [ { values: [ 'name 1', 54 ] },
  { values: [ 'name 2', 34 ] },
  { values: [ 'name 3', 23 ] },
  { values: [ 'name 4', 56 ] } ] }
```

Even after sending correct amount of fields of requested fields, the looker studio gives me the following error,

**Looker Studio has encountered a system error.**

**The number of columns received in the data returned from the community connector
does not match the number of columns requested by Looker Studio. Please report
the issue to the provider of this community connector if this issue persists.**

**Error ID: 97594cad**